# WPF Canvas does not consistently clear drawn geometry

Tags: c#, wpf, vector-graphics

I am working with a WPF control derived from the Canvas that I am drawing a selection of geometry to, through a process that works along these lines, but is far more complex so although this illustrates the process, it is closer to pseudo-code:

```
 public class LineView: Canvas
 {

    private List<GeometryLine> lines;

     public LineView() 
      {
          lines = new List<GeometryLine>();
      }

 private PathFigure GetPathFigure(List<Point> line, bool close)
    { 
        var size = line.Count;
        var points = new PathSegmentCollection(size);
        var first = line.First();
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            points.Add(new LineSegment(line[i], true));

        }
        var figure = new PathFigure(first, points, close);
        return new PathGeometry(new List<PathFigure>(figure));
    }

public DrawingGroup DrawLine(GeometryLine line)
    {
        var geometry = new GeometryGroup();
        geometry.Children.Add(GetPathGeometry(line.Points, false));
        var d = new GeometryDrawing();
        d.Pen = GetPen();
        d.Geometry = geometry;
        DrawingGroup group = new DrawingGroup();
        group.Append();
        group.Children.Add(d);
        return group;
    }

    public override void OnRender(DrawingContext drw) 
    {
         if ( 0 < lines.Count ) 
          {
             foreach ( var line in lines ) 
             {
                   drw.DrawDrawing(DrawLine(line));
              }
          }
    }

    public void SetLines(List<GeometryLine> newLines) 
    {
        lines = newLines;
        this.InvalidateVisual();
    }

 }
```

This all works fine to render geometry content on the canvas. However, when the data changes and `SetLines` is called with a new set of data, it doesn't always clear the canvas - sometimes it will draw the new set of lines over the old set, other times it will clear the canvas. I can't see any pattern as to when it draws over as opposed to when it clears the canvas.

If I call `InvalidateVisual` from the `Render` method it will empty the canvas reliably, but it also forces the context to render again. Past questions on this topic indicate that either `this.Children.Clear()` or `InvalidateVisual` are the recommended strategies, but neither of them prevents this overdrawing problem. When I look at the `Children` collection it is always empty.

What do I need to do in order to ensure it will clear the previous geometry and then draw the updated geometry every time it changes?

Comment: Why `Canvas`? If you need control template (e.g. ability to wrap `ContentPresenter`) - use `Control` at most. You aren't using children, nor attached properties. Another approach would be actually to add children to `Canvas`, then it will take care to draw everything. Children has to be inherited from `Visual` I think (not sure). I found WPF engine too slow to draw anything complicated. A bitmap (bound to content presenter) and gdi+ (`System.Drawing`) can offer extreme performance at cost of fanciness.

Comment: If you are not adding items to your `Canvas.Children` collection, then calling `InvalidateVisual()` *should* be sufficient to force a complete re-render.  The only reason I can think of for it to look like a previous draw is being retained would be if you are somehow adding these figures to your visual tree (either by `AddVisualChild` or `Children`).  Perhaps the geometry you're creating isn't exactly what you *think* it is.  Maybe you should try printing to the console what you're drawing in your OnRender method, and see if it's what you expect.

Comment: @Sinatr I'm using the `Canvas` because from what I could gather it was a good control for drawing geometry onto. I literally only need to draw vector graphics on it right now, though later I will need to be able to catch mouse events and so on. I like the idea of being able to draw fast vector graphics, which is exactly what I am trying to do. Although WPF claims to be designed for that, it doesn't seem able to match SVG in a WebView right now. The WebView is much more difficult to interact with so I would prefer to be WPF native if I can. Is the `Canvas` the wrong control?

Comment: @MikeStrobel given that my goal is to draw geometry items to the canvas, should I be adding the geometry groups to the `Canvas.Children` collection rather than drawing them manually during the `Render` method?

Comment: For the best performance, don't use heavy-weight `Shape` objects or any other framework elements, as they incur overhead for layout and input hit testing.  I would avoid extending `Canvas` and simply extend `Control` or `FrameworkElement` instead.  Keep using the custom rendering, and when you eventually need hit testing, do it yourself.